# Should I choose MvvmLight or MvvmCross on a new project of simple to medium complexity?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm-light, mvvmcross

I am trying to find the main difference between MVVMlight and MVVMCrossthose frameworks. I am planning to develop for Android and Windows Phone. I will use the Xamarin framework. (and Xamarin.Forms)

The project should be a vehicle tracking application that talks to Azure-run server. The app itself will be (as usual in the beginning of a project) very simple (start, stop, keep recorded locations).

Why should I use one over the other?

Other details: VS2012

Comment: Have you considered the option "none"? Xamarin.Forms has built-in MVVM support.

Answer (score 2):

Completely up to you.  People have gotten MvvmCross working with Forms [here](http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2014/07/xamarinforms-and-mvvmcross.html) but still early days.  Do you need any of the nice plugins of MvvmCross?  Will there be screens that you'll need to manage per platform because they are too complicated for Forms?  I don't think there is a right or wrong answer here....

Comment: I wanted to know more about the differences.

Comment: Both are just MVVM frameworks.  I would say that MVVMCross is more opinionated and provides you with more plumbing that has been done for you but you may not agree with those opinions.  I'm not sure if it's the same with MVVMLight but there is a bit of a learning curve to MVVMCross (at least for me as I was not really up to speed on IoC and dependency injection and etc).  There are probably too many differences in totality to discuss here so I would recommend you just play with the frameworks to get an idea of what you can do.