# mvvmcross, how to open another app programatically from another app with parameter

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I using url scheme to open my second app from my first app, I have some parameters that are passed from first app and I read them at OPENURL method in my second app.

But the problem is, OPENURL is called after FinishedLaunching. So I could not use paramaters that I pass from my first app to open second app using those paramaters.

Can any one suggest any best practices how to do it? I am open to any ideas.

Regards
Div

Comment: Look at your previous question as this appears to be a duplicate of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134716/should-i-choose-mvvmlight-or-mvvmcross-on-a-new-project-of-simple-to-medium-comp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A great way of doing this is using the App links standard. There is a Xamarin component called [Rivets](http://components.xamarin.com/view/rivets) which will allow you to integrate this.

It does mean this app you are wanting to link to needs to have App links set up.

Hope this helps...

[Rivets](http://components.xamarin.com/view/rivets)

[App Links](http://applinks.org)